# Plumbing Water Pressure Gauge Slowly (yet still quickly drops) after turning off main water valve

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

I am having a low water pressure issue that started, almost out of no where, about 4 to 6 months ago. Reading my water bill is ambivalent, my water usage is higher but we started using the outdoor water sprinklers more.

It was explained to me, and I also see the same in this video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/_x2E_7abXm8, the following:

If one connects a plumbing [water pressure test gauge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PGXSWF5), *with the main water line on*, gets the reading, in my case `60 PSI`, and then cuts the water main, ***A PRESSURIZED SYSTEM WITHOUT LEAKS WILL REMAIN PRESSURIZED***.

With the above summary, *hopefully accurate*, my question is, *as nothing is perfect*, how long does a home water system remain pressurized? When I cut the main water line, the pressure does drop reasonably swiftly.

[See this recording](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Qdax1zWwzkFhcq4WA)

Turned off in the house at the time of this recording/test is:

- Wash machine OFF
- Dish Washer OFF
- Reverse Osmosis OFF
- Refrigerator OFF
- Toilets OFF

Does the above mean I have a leak somewhere in the system, based on my recording?

*Keep in my mind too, I have already turned off the sprinkler systems and there is zero visible water leaks, this leak, if it exists has been going on for 4 months*

*Historical changes to question:*

- Old video before turning off Dishwasher, Reverse Osmosis, Wash Machine and Refrigerator, [first pressure recording](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5aHfHoxZaRavjNbs5)

Comment: Toilet tanks leaking into the bowl is one suspect.  Any pipes under concrete/underground?

Comment: A noticeable pressure drop during a 15 minute time span is the criterion for failing a water supply test under the IPC. See https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2021P1/chapter-3-general-regulations#IPC2021P1_Ch03_Sec312.5. Yes, you have a leak. Turning off the valve at your hot water tank will compartmentalize the system somewhat for tracing the leak. Any plumbing work around the time of the behavior change could be helpful for tracing the leak.

Comment: You didn't have the water shut off inside the home also during your demonstration, did you? With the water cut off, the pressure comes from elastic expansion of pipes and from the slight compressibility of water, so isolating the leak with valves will increase the pressure loss rate. (You seem to have a minor leak at your testing location.)

Comment: Yes, you have a leak, it might be normal function on pressurized appliances or a break in pipes. Pressurized are, Toilet, Dishwasher, washing machine....close those valves to stop it

Comment: Reverse osmosis filter too.

Comment: There are no under concrete pipes but there is some underground pipes for the sprinkler system. I have turned off Dishwasher, refrigerator, washing machine and all toilets and edited my question with a newly uploaded a new video. I am still seeing, in my recording, what I say is a rapid decline in water pressure once I cut the main.

Comment: @popham there is a slow drip at the water pressure tester connected to the garden hose faucet, I cannot get a perfectly tight seal but that doesn't seem to be enough to have the pressure drop as swiftly as it does

Comment: Based on a water bulk modulus of 300,000 psi and a 40 gallon hot water tank, I get 30 ml water loss necessary to bleed 60 psi down to zero. The pharmacists say that there are 20 drops in 1ml. Since the pipes grow under the pressure, that extra volume has to bleed away also, so the 30 mL is a lower bound on the size of your leak (the pipe volume is so small compared to a water tank that this extra volume is effectively zero). 30 ml is about 2 cubic inches.