# Unknown Change in Water Pressure - Residential Home

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

I have been [doing troubleshooting testing on my home](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/293203/plumbing-water-pressure-gauge-slowly-yet-still-quickly-drops-after-turning-off/293209#293209) to figure out why the shower & sink water pressure has dropped in my home.

So far I know/done the following:

- The water pressure is `60 PSI`
- I have the home system (toilets, dish washer, wash machine, refrigerator) maintaining `60 PSI`(*I did have to exclude the hot water tank & backyard sprinklers from the system to achieve this but, since those two components in the system are OFF and the water pressure is not higher, I am not concerned about that fact now*)
- I have turned the `Pressure-Reducing Valve clockwise`, as much as it will go and there is no improvement in shower/sink water pressure.
- There is no water leaks, *watching the city water meter*, not with the main line on or off.

Knowing all of the above, what can I try or do? I am measuring the water pressure at 60 PSI, which should provide good shower pressure but that is not the case from my perception and memory recall.

Comment: A home water system should be a sealed system till a faucet is open.  60 PSI at one point will be 60 PSI at any other point.  A home system is usually a single line going from point to point with tees.  There might be a partial blockage between the toilet and the sink/shower(if the toilet is before).

Comment: Static pressure versus dynamic pressure. Run a tap somewhere at about half open, and then check the pressure while your regulator has that bit of water flowing through it.

Comment: @crip659 what would cause partial blockage between toilet and shower?

Comment: A blob of sediment or a piece of solder broken off inside the pipe or something.  The placement is just where it got struck.  This assumes that the toilet is before and has 60# but the sink/shower does not have 60#.  Have you checked if the shower/sink has a water flow/pressure saving feature?